# What's the "correct" way to update LiClipse?

Tags: liclipse

I've been using Liclipse for a while, after having supported it in the IndieGogo funding drive a few years ago. However, there are a number of issues that I'm always hopping will get fixed in the next update, yet I haven't found any way to cleanly apply said updates.

The `Help -> Check for Updates` menu doesn't ever show updates to LiClipse, which means the only way I've been able to do it is to download a new copy and overwrite my old one. Unfortunately, this breaks all my existing plugins, so I have to re-install said plugins, which is a petty annoying pain.

I'm using OSX El Capitan, which I think is why plugins get blown aaway upon update? They're all stored in the .app, which gets replaced entirely.

Answer (score 0):

There's a section named "Updating Native Install" in http://www.liclipse.com/download.html which has instructions on how to update the native install (as a note, there really was a bug in the updating of LiClipse through Check for Updates which was fixed in the 4.x version).